# Calling an obsolete class on xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how to call a class that's not in xcode's interface builder?

I am calling QTMovieView on xcode 6 and xcode 6 doesn't have it in the interface builder

my mac app requires that it should install and play movies on 10.6 and later

here's what i've done

I added an object to the View Controller and name it as QTMovieView
and I've connected the property movieView to the QTMovieView.

IS this correct

Comment: What does "onsolete" mean?

Comment: sorry i mean "obsolete"

Comment: is this going to the appstore? if it is, it will be rejected

Comment: it's not going to the app store on apple

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile against the 10.5 SDK.

Comment: is this correct Deployment target is 10.5
Base SDK (latest OSX 10.10)